# java vm initialization error

Tags: java

I recently installed jdk-7u11 for Windows 64-bit. It worked well initially and I successfully compiled and executed my java programs using javac and java. But off late, once I compile a file using javac, it happens smoothly and when I proceed for execution of the file using java, it gives the following error :

Error occurred during initialization of VM

java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

What should I do? I am novice user of jdk and I also tried reinstalling the system after uninstalling it, but that didn't work. What is the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try https://geekycoder.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/java-tips-adventure-in-resolving-the-java-error-error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm/

Comment: and don't install both 32 and 64 bits JVMs

Comment: Thank you so much @gigadot my problem got instantly resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to misconfiguration of PATH and JAVA_HOME. The the java binary and JAVA_HOME should point to the same version of java. Otherwise bad things might happen

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes attempts to load JDBC drivers perform dynamic class load attempts (i.e. reflection based)